# use taxonomy for organic groups

Tags: organic-groups

To lock down access to nodes based on OG's, I have implemented a taxonomy as a group. The users can then can select that taxonomy and access level for each content. Is anyone aware of pitfalls I need to watch out for doing it this way?

I apologize if this is out of scope for this site.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, but I am trying to do something similar.

OG_Menus, taxonomy_menu have seemed to provide a solution. nodeone.se provides a warning, it's unclear if it's been fixed or not. also look at simpleaccess and taxonomy access control.

Comment: Hey user-some-number, I was just digging a bit in your questions/answers and stumbled upon this "so called" answer. Be aware: this is NOT (repeat NOT) an answer. Instead it should have been posted as a comment to the question (at best). I know, you don't have enough "rep" points to post such comments. But know that your "answer" is at risk of being deleted via moderation (only a matter of time for somebody to flag it like so). **Hint**: just suggest 7 edits of questions or answers (to improve them). If they get accepted, you get +2 for each of them 11+7*2=25, enough to post comments!